# Passive voice of "This surface feels smooth"

Tags: exam-questions

What is the difference between following passive voice constructs of the sentence given and which one is correct. Please explain

*Active*- This surface feels smooth.

*Option 1* - This surface is smooth when it is felt.

*Option 2*- This surface when felt is smooth.

Answer (score 2):

None of the options are correct. Your sentence cannot be converted into a sentence in passive voice.

Only sentences with transitive verbs (verbs that require both a subject and an object to operate) can be converted into sentences in passive voice.

[Criteria to check whether a sentence can be converted into passive voice here.](http://www.studyandexam.com/passive-voice-for-intransitive-verb.html)

Your sentence’s verb is ‘feels’. It’s subject is ‘this surface’ but ‘smooth’ is not the object since nothing is being done to ‘smooth’ by the surface.

For example, sentences like “I went to the park” cannot be converted into passive voice (The park was went to by me) because ‘went’ is not a transitive verb in this case. ‘I’ is the subject but there is no object.

Therefore, your sentence cannot be converted into passive voice.